# Условие(больше или равно)

Tags: javascript

Делал задание и получилось так что мне надо сделать условие с "=>".
Пример:

```
if (value1 => value2)
```

Причем значения находятся в объекте, и сравнение выглядит так

```
if (obj.value1 => obj.value)
```

Выдает ошибку как будто это не оператор "больше или равно", а как будто это стрелочная функция. Поискал в интернете, пробовал поставить скобки, менять значения и parseInt и т.д.

Нашел единственный способ:

```
if (obj.value1 > obj.value || obj.value1 = obj.value)
```

Только так работает.

Comment: `>=` ............

Comment: *Выдает ошибку как будто это не оператор "больше или равно"* Так это и есть не "больше или равно", а чёрт те что...

Comment: Из вас выйдет хороший программист - задачу то вы решили! Хотя, надо еще немного внимательности развить.

Comment: Только в вашем обходном манёвре вместо оператора присваивания нужно использовать оператор нестрогого равенства (или равенства с приведением типов): `obj.value1 == obj.value` — или строгого равенства `obj.value1 === obj.value`.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt, я знаю в коде два знака равно, здесь немного перепутал

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , спасибо, извините, я понял в чем моя ошибка, просто не изучил до конца язык, до сих пор изучаю, а это было задание чтоб закрепить пройденное.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg , сделали бы ответ ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в javascript сперва стрелочка идет, а затем равно

```
console.log(1 >= 2); //false
```

Comment: Спасибо, просто то этого я работал на C#, и там с начало идет равно. Это у меня как привычка сохранилось.

Comment: @umid вообще-то там такой же оператор https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators. И `=>` там тоже есть и по смыслу совпадает с JS https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator